# Break lines in blade within {{}} tags

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to put a line break into a blade report.
I know there is the `{!! !!}` tags to escape the html tags, but in my situation I have a long string coming in at `{{$row[$colField]}}` so it already within `{{ }}` tags.

The way I tried it would have appeared like `{{ randome text {!! <br/> !!} }}`.

Is there any other way to do this perhaps.

```
@foreach($fieldList as $field)
    @if ($header->group == $field->group)
    <?php $colName = $field->columnname ?>
    <?php $colField = $field->columnfield; ?>
    <?php $fieldGroup = $field->group; ?>
        @if ($colName != $fieldGroup)
            <span class="titleSpan" style="white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold">{{ $colName=='Age'?'':$colName.':' }} </span>
        @endif
    {{$row[$colField]}}<br>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: add a @ sign before the {} '@{}'

Comment: @ before {{  or @ before the {!!  ?

Comment: Tried both.  `@{!!` just adds the string. `@{{` breaks the whole layout of the report and prints the variables as strings

Comment: Are the line breaks in `$row[$colField]` (as `\n`)?

Comment: tried both `\n` and `\\n`, but both are printed as literal string

Comment: Where exactly you want to place the line break. Inside the text or the html?

Comment: inside `$row[$colField]`  ( 3rd last line). to put each value on a new line.

Comment: Your code seems to like getting desired result

Comment: Yes. His code just looks fine...

Comment: sorry i misinterpreted the question, your code does what you wanted

Comment: Nope, still not solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curly brace blade tags are for echoing values, they don't do anything else and you cannot nest them in the way you're trying to in your example. You can find information about these tags in the [Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data), but in summary:

The double curly brace tag means echo this value and escape it, e.g:

```
{{ $row[$colField] }}
```

compiles to:

```
<?php echo e($row[$colField]); ?>
```

A curly brace with 2 exclamation marks means echo this value without escaping it, e.g:

```
{!! $row[$colField] !!}
```

compiles to:

```
<?php echo $row[$colField]; ?>
```

If you would like for a line break (`<br/>`) to appear somewhere within the value of `$row[$colField]` then you must transform that value *before* outputting it. There are functions, like [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) that can replace new lines with line breaks, so you could for example do this:

```
{!! nl2br($row[$colField]) !!}
```

Which would compile to:

```
<?php echo nl2br($row[$colField]); ?>
```

So if the value of `$row[$colField]` is:

```
Hello world
This is another line.
```

Then that code would output:

```
Hello world</br>
This is another line.
```

---

That said your question is unclear so if this information does not help then please rewrite your question to clearly communicate what you're trying to achieve, i.e: include an example of your input and an example of your desired output.

Comment: Thanks. I change the taggs to `{!! !!}` and send `'<br/>'` along with the values. Works great.